Finding unique subgradient for a differentiable function
I read a proof from some lecture notes:
If $f$ is convex and differentiable at $x$  in $\operatorname{dom}(f) $), then $(\partial f(x) = \{ \nabla f(x) \})$.
Proof
By definition, let $( y = x + \epsilon d ), ( g \in \partial f(x) )$,
$[ f(x + \epsilon d) \geq f(x) + \epsilon g^\top d.$ ]
Then,
$ {f(x + \epsilon d) - f(x)}{\epsilon} \geq g^\top d, \quad \forall d, \forall \epsilon. $
Letting $( \epsilon \to 0 )$, we have
$[ \nabla f(x)^\top d \geq g^\top d, \quad \forall d. ]$
This inequality only holds when $( g = \nabla f(x) )$.
Therefore,
$[ \partial f(x) = \{ \nabla f(x) \}. ]$
My question is this:
when we take $( \epsilon \to 0 )$, we find one solution. But is this unique ? Shouldn't we prove separately that this solution is unique ? Because there might be another $\epsilon$ that gives another solution. This is a general question which applies to other proofs as well.
